# A function in SML that slices a list?

Tags: list, slice, sml

I am trying to write a function in SML that would slice a list.

`Slice x y ls`

ex. `Slice 1 3 [0,1,2,3,4]` and the output `[1,2,3]`

This is what I have to start

```
fun slice(aList, start, stop) = nil;
fun slice(nil, x, y) = []
  | slice(ls, x, y) =
```

> In SML write a slice function, with functionality similar to the Python list slice operator.

For example, `slice ([11, 22, 3, 14, 5, 6], 1, 4)` returns the list `[22, 3, 14]`

Return a slice of a list between indices start inclusive, and stop exclusive. Assume first element of list is at index `0`.

Thank you! I appreciate the help!

Comment: So the first parameter is the value to look for first, then put everything in until you get to the second value? What have you tried so far to solve this problem?

Comment: This is what I have so far, i dont really know how to approach it                                                                                            fun slice(x, y, nil) = 0
    | slice(x, y, ls) =

Comment: Question: can you write a function to return a list ignoring everything _before_ a given value? And can you do the same, but ignoring everything after a given value? Every complex problem is just multiple simpler problems.

Comment: Are `x` and `y` indices or list elements? If `x` is an index, is `y` an index or the length of the slice?

Comment: `0` is not a good base case for a function that produces a list.

Comment: x and y would be the the start and end indices.

Answer (score 3):

### A Basic Solution

How do you know what index you're currently on?

You have to pass that information into the function. Let's call that `cur` for "current."

Slicing an empty list returns an empty list. Slicing a non-empty list should look at the first element in the list, and the current index and if the current index falls into the range provided by `start` and `stop`, add it to the output by appending it onto the result of running the same function on the rest of the list.

```
fun slice([], start, stop, cur) = []
  | slice(x::xs, start, stop, cur) =
    if cur >= start andalso cur <= stop then
      x :: slice(xs, start, stop, cur + 1)
    else
      slice(xs, start, stop, cur + 1)
```

Consider what happens when we evaluate `slice([1, 3, 8, 2, 9, 10, 47], 2, 4, 0)`:

```
slice([1, 3, 8, 2, 9, 10, 47], 2, 4, 0)
slice([3, 8, 2, 9, 10, 47], 2, 4, 1)
slice([8, 2, 9, 10, 47], 2, 4, 2)
8 :: slice([2, 9, 10, 47], 2, 4, 3)
8 :: 2 :: slice([9, 10, 47], 2, 4, 4)
8 :: 2 :: 9 :: slice([10, 47], 2, 4, 5)
8 :: 2 :: 9 :: slice([47], 2, 4, 6)
8 :: 2 :: 9 :: slice([47], 2, 4, 6)
8 :: 2 :: 9 :: slice([], 2, 4, 7)
8 :: 2 :: 9 :: []
[8, 2, 9]
```

### Hiding The Ugly

This works quite nicely, but seeing that current index of `0` passed to the function is ugly. Let's hide that with a local helper function.

```
fun slice(lst, start, stop) =
  let
    fun aux([], start, stop, cur) = []
      | aux(x::xs, start, stop, cur) =
        if cur >= start andalso cur <= stop then
          x :: aux(xs, start, stop, cur + 1)
        else
          aux(xs, start, stop, cur + 1)
  in
    aux(lst, start, stop, 0)
  end
```

### Tail-Call Optimization

And this is good, but can we make it tail-recursive? We can, but we need an accumulator that we pass from one recursive call to the next building up the resulting list. Also, in our base case for `aux`, we don't need to name `start`, `stop`, or `cur` as they are irrelevant to the outcome, so we can use `_` instead.

As we accumulate the result, it will be built up in reverse, so when we return the accumulator, we reverse it.

```
fun slice(lst, start, stop) =
  let
    fun aux([], _, _, _, acc) = List.rev(acc)
      | aux(x::xs, start, stop, cur, acc) =
        if cur >= start andalso cur <= stop then
          aux(xs, start, stop, cur + 1, x::acc)
        else
          aux(xs, start, stop, cur + 1, acc)
  in
    aux(lst, start, stop, 0, [])
  end
```

### Short-Circuiting The Recursion

Now, this iterates over the whole list. We can stop and return the accumulator when `cur` is greater than `stop`. That will save some effort.

```
fun slice(lst, start, stop) =
  let
    fun aux([], _, _, _, acc) = List.rev(acc)
      | aux(x::xs, start, stop, cur, acc) =
        if cur > stop then
          List.rev(acc)
        else if cur >= start andalso cur <= stop then
          aux(xs, start, stop, cur + 1, x::acc)
        else
          aux(xs, start, stop, cur + 1, acc)
  in
    aux(lst, start, stop, 0, [])
  end
```

### Using A Fold

This is yet another place we can apply a fold. `List.foldl` provides a tool we can use to eliminate the recursive iteration from our own function.

Using `foldl` we can pass the index and accumulator from one iteration to the next. Each time we apply a function to that information to transform it for the next iteration. Only if the index is between `start` and `stop` do we add it to the accumulator.

When it's complete, we discard the index information and are left with a resulting list we can reverse.

```
fun slice'(lst, start, stop) =
  let
    val (_, lst') = foldl 
      (fn (v, (idx, acc)) => 
         if idx >= start andalso idx <= stop then 
           (idx + 1, v::acc) 
         else 
           (idx + 1, acc)) 
      (0, []) 
      lst
  in
    List.rev(lst')
  end;
```

### What are we *really* doing?

In this case, "slicing" a list is *filtering* a list based on whether the index of each element is within a range.  So let's define a few new functions. First, `inRange`:

```
fun inRange(start, stop, x) = 
  x >= start andalso x <= stop
```

And then we'll define a function `indexedFilter` that takes a list and a predicate function. The predicate function will take two arguments: an element, and an index. If the predicate returns true, we'll keep that element.

The definition will be in terms of `foldl`.

```
fun indexedFilter(lst, pred) =
  let
    val (lst', _) =
      List.foldl 
        (fn (x, (acc, idx)) => 
           if pred(x, idx) then (x :: acc, idx + 1)
           else (acc, idx + 1))
        ([], 0)
        lst
  in
    List.rev lst'
  end
```

Now `slice` can be defined as:

```
fun slice(lst, start, stop) =
  indexedFilter(lst, fn (_, idx) => inRange(start, stop, idx))
```

Comment: If you don't mind, can you explain the first set of code (basic solution) line by line so i can understand it more?

Comment: That's really getting into very basic territory. What resource or resources are you using to learn?

Comment: I am attempting to help. It seems you're coming at this with very little understanding of syntax and semantics. SO is intended to help with specific, focused questions. If we know what you've had exposure to, we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sml/nj, which includes a nice set of built-ins on the [`List` structure](https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.Empty:EXN:SPEC), you can just do this:

```
fun slice (a,b) xs = List.take (List.drop (xs,a), b-a)
```

That would match the basic (non-negative index) functionality of the python's slice operator.