# how to step over a list in sml?

Tags: sml, smlnj

i have a list , and a tuple `(start,end,interval)`
i am trying to iterate over the list and return the elements that are in list from start to end with interval steps .
for example:

```
cutt [1,2,3,4,77,8,7] (1,5,2);
val it = [2,4,8] : int list;
```

the problem is that i can't use recursion ,
i was thinking to use `foldl` but the problem is how to skip over elements i don't want to use `list.nth`?
i would appriciate little hints ! thank you

Comment: Why can't you use recursion?  Is that an assignment?

Comment: no ! i want to be able to write small functions like those in one liners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to correctly skip elements you don't want in your
resulting list, is to add a parameter to your function used to fold
your list.  The meaning of this parameter is basically "how much items
you still want to skip".

As an example, below is a solution that uses `List.foldl`.  The
function used to fold items of the list takes two parameters: the
first one is the one discussed above and the second one is the
resulting list being constructed.

```ml
fun cutt lst (idx_start, idx_end, interval) = let
    val (_, result) =
        List.foldl
            (fn (x, (0, result)) =>
                (* no more item to skip => add x to the resulting list *)
                (interval - 1, x :: result)
            |   (_, (n, result)) =>
                (* there are still items to skip *)
                (n - 1, result))
            (idx_start, [])  (* initially we skip idx_start items *)
            lst
in
    (* items are prepended in the resulting list in reverse order =>
    reverse the list *)
    List.rev result
end;
                         
val x = cutt [1, 2, 3, 4, 77, 8, 7] (1, 5, 2);
```

Of course the function needs to be adapted as it does not take care
of the `idx_end` parameter.

Comment: thank you! i am actually looking to do it using one liners sml , which means without if statement or pattern matching or recurtion also without let and in thats why this is challenging for me

Comment: Hmm, that seems just infeasible.  Your function will have to perform some tests at some point which means use either pattern matching constructions or if-then-else expressions...

Comment: it is not supposed to be impossible , i am still thinking how to do it but i think it is actually duable using list.take and list.drop and foldl !

Comment: Even when using `List.drop`, we will have to use recursion. If your aim is to have a solution that looks like one liners, and without using anything that actually gets the logic done ... take the function given by @Chris, put them inside a module, and then call them in the function that you intend to write. That way, you should be able to achieve your solution using one liners. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need two functions. The first step is to retrieve a slice of your list between indices. This sounds suspiciously related to [a solution posted very recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70058648/15261315).

> ```
> fun slice'(lst, start, stop) =
>  let
>    val (_, lst') = foldl 
>      (fn (v, (idx, acc)) => 
>         if idx >= start andalso idx <= stop then 
>           (idx + 1, v::acc) 
>         else 
>           (idx + 1, acc)) 
>      (0, []) 
>      lst
>  in
>    List.rev(lst')
>  end;
> ```

If we try `slice'([1,2,3,4,77,8,7], 1, 5)` the result is `[2, 3, 4, 77, 8]`.

To get to `[2, 4, 8]` we just need to drop every second element. This can be defined in terms of simple recursion as follows.

```
fun dropn(n, lst) =
  let 
    fun dropn'(_, _, []) = []
      | dropn'(n, c, x::xs) = 
        if c = n then x :: dropn'(n, 1, xs)
        else dropn'(n, c + 1, xs)
  in
    dropn'(n, n, lst)
  end
```

But apparently you can't use recursion, so let's use a fold.

```
fun drop(n, lst) =
  List.foldl 
    (fn (x, (acc, i)) => if i = n then (x :: acc, 1) else (acc, i + 1))
    ([], n)
    lst
```

Now if we try `drop(2, [1,2,3,4,77,8,7])` we get `([7, 77, 3, 1], 1)` which *does* contain the list we want, but also the counter, and the list is backwards because of the way we've built it up. Let's consider how that accumulator works as we step through this simple example.

```
Initial state: 
  lst: [1,2,3,4,77,8,7]
  acc: []; i: 2

First iteration:
  x: 1
  acc: [1]; i: 2

Second Iteration:
  x: 2
  acc: 1 :: [];  i: 1

Third iteration: 
  x: 3
  acc: 3 :: 1 :: []; i: 2

Fourth iteration:
  x: 4
  acc: 3 :: 1 :: []; i: 1

Fifth iteration:
  x: 77
  acc: 77 :: 3 :: 1 :: []; i: 2

Sixth iteration:
  x: 8
  acc: 77 :: 3 :: 1 :: []; i: 1

Seventh iteration:
  x: 7
  acc: 7 :: 77 :: 3 :: 1 :: []; i: 2

Final step:
  remaining list: []
  acc: 7 :: 77 :: 3 :: 1 :: [] or [7, 77, 3, 1]; i: 1
```

Easy enough, though, to extract and reverse that list.

```
fun drop(n, lst) =
  let
    val (lst', _) = List.foldl 
      (fn (x, (acc, i)) => if i = n then (x :: acc, 1) else (acc, i + 1))
      ([], n)
      lst
  in
    List.rev lst'
  end
```

So now `drop(2, [1,2,3,4,77,8,7])` evaluates to `[1, 3, 77, 7]`.

Between these two answers, it should be very straightforward to put together a solution to your problem, and hopefully to see why it works.

Comment: thank you! i am actually looking to do it using one liners sml , which means without if statement or pattern matching or recurtion also without let and in thats why this is challenging for me

Comment: Please note that even using something like `foldl` is basically just "out-sourcing" recursion. These are absurd requirements, and even if it were possible, I don't see what educational value "SML golf" could possibly have.

Comment: yes i know that foldl is a recursuc function but i can't think of a different way to implement cutt without it ! it is not supposed to be impossible , i am still thinking how to do it but i think it is actually duable using list.take and list.drop and foldl !