# how to iterate over a list using one liner msl?

Tags: sml, smlnj

i have a list , and a tuple (start,end,interval) i am trying to iterate over the list and return the elements that are in list from start to end with interval steps . for example:

```
cutt [1,2,3,4,77,8,7] (1,5,2);
val it = [2,4,8] : int list;
```

the problem is that i want to write a function that does this using one line only which means no recursic function and no if condition also no pattern matching

i began by thinking i can cutt the list first only to elements between start and end using :

```
fun cutt list1 (start,end,interval) = List.drop(List.take(list1 ,end+1),start);
```

and now i want to use maybe foldl or foldr to only get elements in interval jumps , my problem is how to iterate over the list ?

Comment: More than one very good programmer [has told you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143347/how-to-step-over-a-list-in-sml#comment123997501_70144808) that what you're asking is impossible or at the very best, not feasible. Creating a new question to ask the same thing again is not particularly respectful. Do not be surprised if this question is closed.

Comment: When you clarified that you were looking for that, no fewer than three people told you it was either impossible or not feasible. If we could provide a solution, we would have done it there. I would be very interested to see your professor's solution that meets all of those criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, after much soul-searching, we *can* do this, but it's hideously ugly and inefficient and **should not be done**.

Let's first off drop the elements you want dropped. Your basic recipe works, but you can't use `end` as that is a reserved word.

```
fun cutt list1 (start, stop, interval) = 
  List.drop(List.take(list1, stop + 1), start);
```

`cutt [1,2,3,4,77,8,7] (1, 5, 2)` yields `[2,3,4,77,8]`.

Now, how do we drop elements at an interval. We can't use explicit recursion, nor pattern matching or conditions. Well, then we can use `List.tabulate` to create a list equal to our lists length that has tuples with the list elements and an index.

```
fun cutt list1 (start, stop, interval) = 
  List.tabulate(
    stop - start + 1, 
    (fn i => 
       (i, List.nth(List.drop(List.take(list1, stop + 1), start), i))));
```

If we evaluate `cutt [1,2,3,4,77,8,7] (1, 5, 2)` now we get `[(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 77), (4, 8)]`.

Now we can filter based on the index to throw out the values we don't want.

```
fun cutt list1 (start, stop, interval) = 
  List.filter (fn (i, _) => i mod interval = 0) (List.tabulate(
    stop - start + 1, 
    (fn i => 
       (i, List.nth(List.drop(List.take(list1, stop + 1), start), i)))));
```

`cutt [1,2,3,4,77,8,7] (1, 5, 2)` yields `[(0, 2), (2, 4), (4, 8)]`.

And we can map out the indexes.

```
fun cutt list1 (start, stop, interval) = 
  List.map (fn (_, x) => x) (List.filter (fn (i, _) => i mod interval = 0) (List.tabulate(
    stop - start + 1, 
    (fn i => 
       (i, List.nth(List.drop(List.take(list1, stop + 1), start), i))))));
```

`cutt [1,2,3,4,77,8,7] (1, 5, 2)` yields `[2, 4, 8]`.

Stunningly ugly and inefficient. I'm not sure why anyone is teaching you to write code this way. Feel free to make it *extra ugly* by removing the newlines.

```
fun cutt list1 (start, stop, interval) = List.map (fn (_, x) => x) (List.filter (fn (i, _) => i mod interval = 0) (List.tabulate(stop - start + 1, (fn i => (i, List.nth(List.drop(List.take(list1, stop + 1), start), i))))));
```